# Google Sheets API v4 Method: spreadsheets.values.append only updates one cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

For some reason, despite my ranges being specified, my list updates the D2 cell, instead of doing the subsequent cells below it.  For example, when I run my code the cell D2 will be appropriately updated with 'A'.  Then when it makes another loop, instead of moving to D3, it updates D2 again with 'B'.  This repeats until I'm just left with the last value generated from the for loop.

Attached is my code, sorry for readability I'm new.

```
import requests
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

consumer_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)



tickerlist= ['CUE', 'FB', 'AMD']





# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range = 'Sheet1!D2:D').execute()
values = result.get('values',[])

#open payload (this is where I'm getting my list from)
payload = {'apikey':consumer_key,
           'periodType':'day',
           'frequencyType':'minute',
           'frequency':'30',
           'period':'1',
           'needExtendedHoursData':'false',
           'startDate': '1620619200000'}

#for OPN loop

for i in tickerlist:
        #definitions

        endpoint = r'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/{}/pricehistory'.format(i)
        content = requests.get(url=endpoint, params = payload)
        emptlist = []
        
        #turn data into OPN JSON

        data = content.json()
        del data['symbol']
        del data['empty']
        for key in data:
                for nested_dict in data[key]:
                        if 'volume' in nested_dict:
                                del nested_dict['volume']
                        if 'close' in nested_dict:
                                del nested_dict['close']
                        if 'high' in nested_dict:
                                del nested_dict['high']
                        if 'low' in nested_dict:
                                del nested_dict['low']
                        if 'datetime' in nested_dict:
                                del nested_dict['datetime']
                        emptlist += nested_dict.values()
                        llist = [emptlist]
        #isolating first element

        fopenlist = llist[0]
        openlist = fopenlist[0]
        trueopenlist = [[openlist]]
        
        #plugging OPN into sheets
        
        request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                        range='Sheet1!D2:D', valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body={'values': actualopenlist}).execute()
```

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: In your script, it seems that spreadsheets.values.append method is not used. If I misunderstood your script, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*Use [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) to append values to a Spreadsheet*

> The input range is used to search for existing data and find a "table" within that range. Values will be appended to the next row of the table, starting with the first column of the table.